# Prevent brightness restore after screen unlocked in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiscreen

I changed my screen brightness using `UIScreen`, and from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/brightness), the screen brightness will be restored to the system setting when the iPhone is locked and then turned back on.

Is there any way to prevent or work around this case?

I want the brightness to stay the same value set by `UIScreen` when I lock and then unlock my phone.

Answer (score 0):

It's a similar situation with sound and is an understandable limitation. Giving apps an interface to Global settings would lead to apps basically doing whatever they want, potentially degrading the users' experience.

If you really need the setting to persist, try linking your users to the Settings app where they can change it themselves.